# Symfony 2 Validator - how to return an array

Tags: php, json, validation, symfony

I need the Symfony2 Validator to return an array rather than an object.

So something like this:

```
$insert = new MyEntity();
$insert->setTest1( 'testtesttest' );
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($insert);
```

...would enable this:

```
$errors[0]['message'] = "The email is not valid"
```

Just a simple array as parsing the object returned is very difficult.

I understand the validator config, but I just need the Validator to return an array not its usual object.

I'm JSON encoding the result and (a) json_encode struggles with objects + (b) I don't want to return the whole object just a list of errors.

I'm not using the in-built forms, just the raw Validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Validator->validate()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator.html#method_validate) returns a object of [`ConstraintViolationListInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintViolationListInterface.html), which implements the [`IteratorAggregate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) interface. Simple foreach over it and construct your desired array out of the [`ConstraintViolationInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintViolationInterface.html) objects.

Comment: You can't foreach over it as it is an object with only private properties

Comment: False. Have you read my answer? `validate()` returns a traversable list, over which you can iterate with foreach and the foreach should return objects of `ConstraintViolationInterface`

Answer (score 5):

You can loop over the objects to create an array of errors.

```
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate( $insert );

$errorArray = array();

foreach($errors as $error)
{
    $errorArray[$error->getPropertyPath()] = $error->getMessage();
}
```