# Getting a specific value from Twig array (using Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, twig

So I can do this:

```
{% for x in data %}
    {{ x.label }}: {{ x.value }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

But I want to do this kind of thing to get one specific value:

```
{{ data['label' }}
```

I can't see how to do it, but it must be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

{{ attribute(data,'label') }}

Comment: Thanks, but I just can't get this to work. I think it's because 'data' is a http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintViolationList.html - it's the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514559/symfony-2-validator-how-to-return-an-array/17516635#17516635 but using Twig (so I'm passing $errors through to Twig)

Comment: your question was how to access an array value using a string as key in twig ... i kindly provided a correct answer to your question. Please upvote/accept -> open a new question like "how to ouput validator errors passed to twig" and i will kindly help you over there aswell. ... validator errors are returned as an array of objects by the way, not a pure array ... which easily explains why you don't succeed this way.

Comment: No problem, I saw this as the same question, but I have no problem opening new ones

Comment: I've posted another question. Thanks again for you help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517521/getting-specific-error-message-in-twig-that-was-generated-from-symfony2-validato