# Getting specific error message in Twig that was generated from Symfony2 Validator

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm passing $errors to Twig, generated from this:

```
$insert = new MyEntity();
$insert->setTest1( 'testtesttest' );
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($insert);
```

...how do I get a specific error value, something like this if it worked?

```
{{ errors('field1') }}
```

...which should just return the error message, e.g. "That is not a valid email address" etc.

I know I can loop through to get all of them:

```
{% for err in errors %}
    {{ err.label }}: {{ err.value }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

...but I just want one specific one

Comment: didn't you already ask how to convert the errors to an array? what exactly do you want to achieve with your validation? what are you validating? wouldn't maybe a form suit here? ... a list of all errors , fields and messages separated by : and followed by a <br/> ? ... or will there another question be following :)

Comment: You asked me to post this question as you said it was different to the other one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516070/getting-a-specific-value-from-twig-array-using-symfony2/17516096#17516096 I just need to get one specific value from the Validation errors object when passed to Twig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant just access the fieldname of an array of validation-error objects directly. You have to search it by looping.

```
{% for error in errors %}
   {% if error.propertyPath = 'fieldname' %}
      {{ error.propertyPath }}: {{ error.message }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But maybe you're better off just using ...

```
$errors = $validator->validateProperty($insert, 'fieldname);
```

... in your controller and just passing the list of errors for the one property into your template.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. I thought about doing that but I'm trying to use as many best practices as possible. I hoped for a simple {{ errors(field name) }} thing. Thanks again

Comment: that's possible using forms `{{ form_errors(form.fieldName) }}` , maybe you should look into the `getErrorsAsString` form method and/or dig deeper how it's done in the form component.

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning Symfony2 and haven't got to forms yet. It's one of the next topics though. None of what I'm doing is for production, it's all self-learning, so I thought I would thoroughly do a topic at a time.